# Создание своей библиотеки Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-library

У меня есть служебный класс для отладки приложений с нужными мне статическими методами. Надоело таскать его от проекта к проекту копированием, хочу создать на его основе простую библиотеку, которую залью на GitHub. В дальнейшем планирую подключать эту библиотеку к проектам через **Module dependency**, т.е. просто как исходный код.

Пытаюсь разобраться. Как я понимаю, нужно создать модуль **File -> New Module**, далее выбрать **Android Library**. Далее создается модуль, который находится на одном уровне с **app**. Теперь вопрос: что из этих двух модулей моя библиотека? где должен быть расположен код библиотеки - в **app** или в только что созданном модуле? что именно мне заливать на GitHub, чтобы потом я смог это использовать в своих проектах? (так же я не могу понять, нужно ли создавать для библиотеки проект)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классы вашей библиотеки должны находиться в только что созданном модуле. Как [понятно](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#auto/ru/app) из названия модуля `app` - это приложение. Следовательно в другом модуле - библиотека.

А вообще можно создать отдельный проект и залить его на GitHub. Так будет чище. Проще всего использовать [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io) для распространения либы. Для джитпака в репозиторий на ГХ обязательно нужно залить папку `gradle/wrapper`, всё остальное на Ваше усмотрение.